# Microsoft Visual C++ code optimization

Tags: c++, optimization

In MSVC, there are four options for code optimization:

- No Optimization
- Minimize Size
- Maximize Speed
- Full Optimization

The first three are self-explanatory, but I am unsure about `Full Optimization`. Does this try to find a balance between size and speed, or does it do better optimization than the other two options? Please clarify what it means.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears to be speed optimization, with some extra optimizations turned on. It's fully explained online [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59a3b321%28VS.80%29.aspx).

> Using /Ox is the same as using the
>   following options:
>
> /Obn, where n = 2
>
> /Og (Global Optimizations)
>
> /Oi (Generate Intrinsic Functions)
>
> /Os, /Ot (Favor Small Code, Favor Fast
>   Code)
>
> /Oy (Frame-Pointer Omission)
>
> Note   The use of Full Optimization
>   implies the use of the Frame Pointer
>   Omission (/Oy (Frame-Pointer
>   Omission)) option.